Meaning of "fruit" in Song of Solomon 4:16

Awake, O north wind, And come, O south! Blow upon my garden, That its spices may flow out. Let my beloved come to his garden And eat its pleasant fruits. (4:16)
I have come to my garden, my sister, my spouse; I have gathered my myrrh with my spice; I have eaten my honeycomb with my honey; I have drunk my wine with my milk. Eat, O friends! Drink, yes, drink deeply, O beloved ones (5:1)

She asks him to eat fruit. I think fruit would mean smth like apple or grape. But what he does is consuming honey, wine, milk and gathering myrhh and spice

Which commentaries have you read so far? - https://biblehub.com/commentaries/songs/4-16.htm.

I suggest you read this in context - the Song of Solomon is one of the most beautify erotic love poems ever written.  Because this is a "family-friendly" site let me just suggest that these two verses are the literary center of the book and the "climax" of the entire work.

The answer to the question about 4:16 is given in the very next verse (5:1)
בָּ֣אתִי לְגַנִּי֮ אֲחֹתִ֣י כַלָּה֒ אָרִ֤יתִי מוֹרִי֙ עִם־בְּשָׂמִ֔י אָכַ֤לְתִּי יַעְרִי֙ עִם־דִּבְשִׁ֔י שָׁתִ֥יתִי יֵינִ֖י עִם־חֲלָבִ֑י אִכְל֣וּ רֵעִ֔ים שְׁת֥וּ וְשִׁכְר֖וּ דּוֹדִֽים׃ {ס}

I have come to my garden, My own, my bride; I have plucked my myrrh
and spice, Eaten my honey and honeycomb, Drunk my wine and my milk.
Eat, lovers, and drink: Drink deep of love! (JPS)

Fruit and other delicacies are often a sexual symbol, both in the Bible and elsewhere. In 4:16, the woman invites her husband to her bed. She herself is both the garden and its fruit. In 5:1, it is the man who speaks, after having responded to her invitation. This is followed by a declaration by the narrator or chorus: "Drink deep of love!"  This much seems clear. The interpretation is varied. Many understand it to be an allegory of God and Israel, or of Christ and his Bride. Others understand the Song to have originally been written as a kind of play with either an erotic or a spiritual theme (or both).
